# JPA map multiple rows into List

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hello is there way so java can map multiple rows of joined tables with reference OneToMany into list?

I need to use view, because there are some conditions I need to have, but I get multiple rows from this join because one entity is referenced more times, like this:
We can have foo and bar, where bar references foo:

View:

```
SELECT
     foo.id fooID,
     foo.name fooName,
     b.id barID
FROM foo
          LEFT JOIN bar b on b.foo_id = foo.id
          LEFT JOIN bar_properties bp ON b.property_id = bp.id
          LEFT JOIN bar_states bs ON b.state_id = bs.id
    WHERE
          bs.name = 'active'
          bp.name = 'NEW'
```

RESULTS

```
fooID   fooName   barId
22,     test2,    1
22,     test2,    2
23,     test3,    3
```

In Java after I call ViewRepository.findAll() I need to get only 2 records (not 3), but I need to have multiple records in my @OneToMany list like this:

```
fooID   fooName   bars
22,     test2,    [1,2]
23,     test2,    [3]
```

I tried using annotation like this in my view model:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "foo", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @Where(clause = "")
    private final List<Bar> bars = new ArrayList<>();
```

But I could not get right the way how to use multiple other entities in this where condition.
For example states or properties of bar, which are in other tables.

Answer (score 0):

this just a small idea, why not use transiant object and set your list by hand using a listener whith the PostLoad annotation. I don't know where it could lead. You must remove what causes your select to return multiple lines.